Geometric mean of the nonzero numbers in the Cantor set $ C $
I am interested in finding the geometric mean of the nonzero numbers in the Cantor set $ C $.
Background

The Cantor set $ C \subset [0,1] $ is constructed by repeatedly removing the middle third of intervals:

Start with $ C_0 = [0,1] $.

Start with $ C_0 = [0,1] $.

At each step $ n \geq 1 $, construct $ C_n $ by removing the open middle third of each closed interval in $ C_{n-1} $.

The Cantor set is $ C = \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty C_n $.


An equivalent characterization of $ C $ is:
$  
C = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k} \ \Bigg| \ a_k \in \{0, 2\} \ \text{for all} \ k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}.  
$
That is, $ C $ consists of all numbers in $[0,1]$ whose base-3 (ternary) expansions involve only the digits 0 and 2.
My Questions

-
Is it meaningful to define the geometric mean of the nonzero numbers in $ C $?} If so, how can we rigorously define it in this context, given that $ C $ is uncountable and has Lebesgue measure zero?

What is the value of the geometric mean of the nonzero numbers in $ C $? Is it zero, or can it be assigned a positive value through an appropriate definition?
Does employing a probability measure on $ C $, such as the natural Cantor measure $ \mu $, assist in defining and computing the geometric mean? If so, how is this measure defined, and how does it facilitate the calculation?

Attempts and Considerations


Defining the Geometric Mean

For a finite set of positive numbers $ \{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n $, the geometric mean $ G $ is:
$  
G = \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{1/n}.  
$
For an uncountable set like $ C $, especially one of measure zero, this definition does not directly apply. One approach is to consider the geometric mean in terms of the exponential of the expected value of $ \ln X $ with respect to a probability measure on $ C $:
$  
G = \exp\left( \int_C \ln x \, d\mu(x) \right).  
$

Cantor Measure $ \mu $

The natural probability measure on $ C $, often called the Cantor measure, can be constructed as follows:

Assign probabilities to the left and right intervals at each step of the Cantor set construction.

This results in a measure $ \mu $ where each interval at stage $ n $ has measure $ 2^{-n} $.

Equivalently, $ \mu $ can be defined on the sigma-algebra generated by $ C $ such that for sequences $ (a_k) $ with $ a_k \in \{0, 2\} $:


$  
\mu\left( \left\{ x \in C \ : \ x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k} \right\} \right) = 2^{-n},  
$  

where $ n $ is the number of specified digits in the ternary expansion.  

Calculating the Expected Value

Consider the random variable $ X $ taking values in $ C $ according to $ \mu $.
The expected value $ E[\ln X] $ is:
$  
E[\ln X] = \int_C \ln x \, d\mu(x).  
$
Since $ C $ contains numbers arbitrarily close to zero (but not zero, except possibly at $ x=0 $), $ \ln x $ approaches $ -\infty $ as $ x \to 0^+ $.
Because $ \mu $ assigns positive measure to intervals containing such small $ x $, the integral diverges:
$  
E[\ln X] = -\infty.  
$
Therefore, the geometric mean is:
$  
G = \exp\left( E[\ln X] \right) = \exp( -\infty ) = 0.  
$
I seek a rigorous mathematical explanation or confirmation of the above reasoning. Specifically:

Is the approach of using the Cantor measure $ \mu $ to define the
geometric mean appropriate in this context?

Is the conclusion that the geometric mean of the nonzero numbers in $C $ is zero correct?

Are there alternative ways to define or interpret the geometric mean
for such sets that might yield a finite, positive value?


Any insights, corrections, or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Please, take the time to format your question, not just copy-paste a file.

Marginally related: 27 May - 06 June 2010 sci.math thread center of mass of the Cantor set. See also: Canadian Mathematical Bulletin 11 #2 (June 1968), pp. 306-307.

This may seem odd, but even with a zero entry the limiting geometric mean of the Cantor set is greater than zero. In fact it's greater than or equal to $2/9$.
Define $x_{1,1}=2/3$ as the only nonzero "initial" point of the segments after the first division. From this we generate three such points after the next division:
$x_{2,1}=2/9=x_{1,1}/3$
$x_{2,2}=2/3=x_{1,1}$
$x_{2,3}=8/9=x_{2,1}+2/3$
We may iterate on thusbprocess, generating $2^k$ new entries at stage $k$ acvording to the recursions
$x_{k,i}=x_{k-1,i}/3, 0<i<2^{k-1}$
$x_{k,2^{k-1}}=2/3$
$x_{k,2^{k-1}+i}=x_{k,i}+2/3, 0<i<2^{k-1}$
If we calculate tge geometric mean $\overline{x}_k$ for each $k$ with small $k$ we get
$\overline{x}_1\approx0.667$
$\overline{x}_2\approx0.509$
$\overline{x}_3\approx0.413$
$\overline{x}_4\approx0.356$
$\overline{x}_5\approx0.323$
$\overline{x}_6\approx0.303$
$\overline{x}_7\approx0.291$
The numbers start out getting smaller but the decreasebis apparently slowing down quite rapidly as if there were a bound greater than zero.
From the recursion relation we may render
$2/3\overline{x_{k-1}}>\overline{x}_k>\sqrt{\overline{x}_{k-1}×2/3}$
and infer that if any geometric mean exceeds $2/9$, the next one will also, and by mathematical induction all the geometric means do so. So the limit us at least $2/9$. If we assume that the decrement in the geometric kean for each step in $k$ decays exponentially for larger $k$, the numerical results converge to about $0.28$.
